# Insert data on a table from stored procedure resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that gets data from different tables. I want a few fields from the result set of the stored procedure to be inserted on another table.

How can I do this? Cursor, another stored procedure or what?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You say that you want a few fields from the resultset inserted? Does that mean that you still want all the rows from the resultset?

Comment: No, the resultset gets 20 rows and I just want 15 of them to be inserted in the table

Comment: But all the columns? How do you select which rows you don't want?

Comment: Well, that´s part of the problem. I just need a few rows of that resultset to be inserted on the table and how to do it

Comment: I understand that - how would you describe - in code - which records to insert? What would distinguish these rows from the others?

Comment: By creating a temp table.I found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197844/inserting-updating-data-on-table-from-a-stored-procedure-result-set it´s very helpful but I don´t know how to do it when having fewer columns in the table.

Answer (score 3):

You can insert the result set from a stored procedure into another table, as in this example from [this article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/stored-procedures-returning-data):

```
DECLARE @People TABLE
(
    ContactID INT,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
    LastName NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT @People (ContactID, FirstName, LastName)
EXEC dbo.GetPeopleByLastName @LastName = 'Alexander'
```