# SQL - Changing column values based on temporary table dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

SQL Server Mgt Studio 2012 is what I'm using. To sum it up im wanting to execute several commands at once.  I'm a .NET developer so i think in terms of if and elses.

I have raw data in [TableData] like this:

```
ID | Code 1 | Code 2 | Type Code | From Date | Thru Date | Adj Code | Final
1  | 2001   | 9982   | 10        | 2015-01-13| 2015-01-13| 0        | Y
2  | 2001   | 9982   | 10        | 2015-01-13| 2015-01-13| 1        | N
3  | 2001   | 9982   | 10        | 2015-01-13| 2015-01-24| 2        | Y
4  | 2001   | 2653   | 40        | 2014-12-29| 2014-12-29| 0        | Y
5  | 2001   | 2653   | 40        | 2014-12-29| 2014-12-29| 1        | N
```

I inserted data from TableData into a temporary table called TempData where AdjCode = 1.

tmp table [TempData] data:

```
ID | Code 1 | Code 2 | Type Code | From Date | Thru Date | Adj Code 
1  | 2001   | 9982   | 10        | 2015-01-13| 2015-01-13| 1
2  | 2001   | 2653   | 40        | 2014-12-29| 2013-12-29| 1
```

I want to examine each row in TempData by the [Type Code].

If the [Type Code] is '10' then I want to do a new select on TableData  where TempData's [Code 1], [Code 2], [Type Code], and [From Date] columns Match.

That should look like this :

```
ID | Code 1 | Code 2 | Type Code | From Date | Thru Date | Adj Code | Final
1  | 2001   | 9982   | 10        | 2015-01-13| 2015-01-13| 0        | Y
2  | 2001   | 9982   | 10        | 2015-01-13| 2015-01-24| 2        | Y
```

Then based off this recordset, If there is an [Adj Code] with '2' I want to update corresponding TableData's [Final] column 'Y'. Similarly, i woudl liek to update matching TableData's matching record with 'N'  for [Final] column 'N' where [Adj Code] = 0.

If the [Type Code] is anything other than '10' (the other one with '40' in this case), I want to do the same process except add the [Thru Date] as well... looks like this:
 select on TableData  where TempData's [Code 1], [Code 2], [Type Code], and [From Date] AND [Thru Date] columns Match.

That should look like this:

```
ID | Code 1 | Code 2 | Type Code | From Date | Thru Date | Adj Code | Final
1  | 2001   | 2653   | 40        | 2014-12-29| 2014-12-29| 0        | Y
2  | 2001   | 2653   | 40        | 2014-12-29| 2014-12-29| 1        | N
```

I hope this isnt too confusing...  I'd be glad to provide more information  as i need to complete this for a project at work asap.  Thanks.

Comment: Please show your Sql. you are have to write store proc for this. good luck

Comment: I don't have any sql written yet.

Comment: I solved this by using a nested cursors.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469019/cursor-inside-cursor

Comment: please answer your question and marked complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used nested cursors following this article: stackoverflow.com/questions/469019/cursor-inside-cursor

While it is a temporary solution and works, the runtime is incredibly slow with cursors.  It takes over an hour to complete my query (hits over 90k records).